# error loading repositories in Android Studio for importing into Google Cloud Source Repository

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-source-repos

When importing Android project into VCS (Google Cloud source repositories), I'm able to select the cloud project, but getting following error for viewing repositories:

[image]

I'm following this doc to import project: https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/vcs.

```
Project level build.gradle:

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Please share your project-level `build.gradle file. And also, just make sure the internet connection is okay as well.

Comment: @ReazMurshed, updated please check. I'm getting this error for other projects as well. Could it be permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

I can see three possible causes:

1. A permissions issue, please remember to set up authentication
   properly with one of the three methods
   [here](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pushing-code-from-a-repository).
2. A mix-up between the Project Name and the [Project
       ID](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)
   (use the Project ID only) on Android Studio's dialog box.
3. Not having set up the "default" repository on the GCP project. To
   create a repository on  your Google Cloud Project follow this
   [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart)
   and name your repository default.

Answer (score 0):

My solution which is less than ideal is to fall back to using git via https. The steps for setting this up are provided in the GCP source repository under clone -> manually generated credentials (basically you run a cmd or bash script to store a git cookie).